# Can I use Custom Java objects in Apache axis1

Tags: java, web-services, axis

suppose I have a class

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private String country
}
```

and in web-service method rahter using a String array I want to recieve a Person object. Can this be done in apache axis 1?

```
public boolean savePerson(Person per)
```

I am using eclipse juno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed you can.

The easiest way may be to create a WSDL file describing the data format for your objects. Axis will then allow you to generate converters between XML and your POJOs.

See http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Using_WSDL_with_Axis for more information.

Comment: I want to create a webservice not client

Comment: WSDL can be used on client and server side.